# Google Apps Script deleting Drive file causes Error

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create and delete a spreadsheet in Apps Script but everytime I run it the following Error is thrown.

> Document (*my file id*) is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)

The file is deleted but the script execution stops.

The variable tempdoc isn't used after the file was deleted.

Drive API is enabled

Does anybody know how to avoid this issue?

```
function create_do_delete(){

  var tempdoc = SpreadsheetApp.create('TEST3')
  
  tempdoc.getSheets()[0].getRange('A1').setValue('TEST3')
  
  console.log(tempdoc.getId())  

  var pdf = tempdoc.getAs('application/pdf').setName('TEST3')

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(*my_id*)
  folder.createFile(pdf)

  Drive.Files.remove(tempdoc.getId())

  return pdf
}
```

It works this way but I don't understand why.

```
function create_do_delete(){

  var tempdoc = SpreadsheetApp.create('TEST3')
  
  tempdoc.getSheets()[0].getRange('A1').setValue('TEST3')
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  console.log(tempdoc.getId())  

  var pdf = tempdoc.getAs('application/pdf').setName('TEST3')

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(*my_id*)
  folder.createFile(pdf)

  Drive.Files.remove(tempdoc.getId())

  return pdf
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work the first time either but I did notice that the first  pdf didn't  have any contents which would have made me think to use SpreadsheetApp.flush() also.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of operations in your code could have resulted in a **race condition** in which the spreadsheet creation have not have propagated fully to all Google services such as the Drive API before the deletion occurred.

`SpreadsheetApp.flush()` was placed to complete the execution of the code above before executing the code below.

**References:**

[SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)